# How to make div or button in google maps web api v3 infowindow clickable by mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a web page using Google maps API v3 that I want to be mobile friendly.  I've included a clickable div in the infoWindow that works fine on a PC but is ignored on a mobile device.  I tried adding a button to the internal div but that wasn't clickable on a mobile device either.

Is there a way to do this?

Sample infoWindow content:

```
sDesc = '<div id="infowindow" onclick="openDetail()"><div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">My Title</div>Some extra info here<br>More info</div>';
infoWindow.setContent(sDesc);
infoWindow.marker = marker;
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: The posted code works for me if the `openDetail` function is in the global scope (if it isn't, I get a javascript error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: openDetail is not defined`).  [working fiddle (at least on my Android phone)](http://jsfiddle.net/gb854fn9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the browser on the mobile device.  After digging around on the issues site, I found one that was similar but about the close button not working.  It gave a link to supported browsers, which doesn't include the normal Android browser.  Chrome for Android works as expected, however.

Here's a link to the issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5397